# proving a complete sufficent statistics

Tags: statistics

Suppose that $ X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are iid poisson($b$); $c = b^2$ and $S_n = \sum X_i$

To Show that $S_n$ is a complete sufficient statistic for $c$.
I can prove using exponential family that $S_n$ is sufficient for $b$, but how may I prove it for $b^2$? 
Will anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

If the conditional probability distribution of $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ given $S_n$ depends on $b^2$, then it depends on $b$.  Since it does not depend on $b$, it therefore does not depend on $b^2$.

Comment: Are there any theorem that proves this? in order to mention it in the question solution

Comment: You can write an argument as follows: The conditional distribution of $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ given $S_n$ when $c=b_1^2$ is the same as the conditional distribution of $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ given $S_n$ when $b=b_1$.  That last is the same as the conditional distribution of $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ given $S_n$ when $b=\text{a different number }b_2$, since you've already proved that $S_n$ is sufficient, and finally _that_ distribution_ is the same as the conditional distribution of $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ given $S_n$ when $c=b_2^2$. ${}\qquad{}$